# Testing (Firebase) FCM

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In order to understand how to use `Firebase Cloud Messaging`, I am following this document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages?hl=en-us

Precisely I am looking at this section: *Send to individual devices*

I can see in the code that I need a *registrationToken*. My question is how do I concretely get one?

I first want to send a message to my own iPhone, laying on my desk and later to all iPhones of registered users.

Answer (score 1):

When I work in IOS-Swift, you have to add this method in your AppDelegate.swift file:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken:  String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

If you need to access the token directly, use this:

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
   if let error = error {
      print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
   } else if let result = result {
     print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
     self.instanceIDTokenMessage.text  = "Remote InstanceID token: \(result.token)"
   }
  }
```

For more information visit:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: I have tried what you suggest, I may be doing something the wrong way, but it seems like the function messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken is never called. Do you have an idea about the problem?

Comment: After searching the net I found out that I was not following the right order when performing all the steps. In the meanwhile you gave me a valuable tip. Thanks a lot. This other post https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1339 helped me knock down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When working with FCM notifications, the devices generate tokens, which are renewed every so often, so if you need to send a push to a device you must know your token, you must implement a class that inherits FirebaseMessagingService, and overwrite an onNewToken method, this method is called in the background every time the device token is updated.

```
/**
* Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
* the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the     InstanceID token
* is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
*/
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}
```

It is recommended that this token be sent to your server so that from there you can send the push to the devices with registered tokens. If you want to force a first token, you can use:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId();
```

Comment: You code is not Swift, I am working with an iOS app written in Swift.
I will try to find corresponding function in Swift.